# Inductance of block of metal vs wire

Tags: electromagnetism

For a simple wire, the magnetic field and corresponding inductance (supposed the source is high frequency current) are:

[image]

How about for block of metal such as the following?

[image]

Where does the magnetic field flow? Do you think it has more or less inductance than the piece of wire?